# Jump bar (similar to XCode's) control for Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've identified Xcode's jump bar as something that would prove very useful in one of my applications. I've searched high and low (both internet and in Apple's documentation), and haven't come up with an available implementation of the jump bar or a similar control.

Is there a publicly available jump-bar control?

EDIT: See Apple's description of the jump bar in XCode [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-jump_bar/Recipe.html) if you don't know what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this might be what you are looking for: [GCJumpBar](https://github.com/gcamp/GCJumpBar)